# the smash product of maps?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$  be a   map, which is NOT null homotopic. Denote the constant map of $S^n$ by   $*$ , then what is the homotopy type of the resulting smash product $f\wedge *：X\wedge S^n\to Y\wedge S^n$ ?
I guess it is nullhomotopic. Is the following proof  right?

It follows from the fact that the map $f\wedge k:X\wedge S^n\to Y\wedge S^n$ is homotopic to $kf:\Sigma^n X\to \Sigma^n Y$, by the standard homotopy equivalence $\Sigma^nX\simeq X\wedge S^n$, where $k$ is an integer.

Moreover, if $g:Z\to W$ is a nullhomotopic map, then is the smash product $f\wedge g:X\wedge Z\to Y\wedge W$ null homotopic?

Answer (score 0):

If "nullhomotopic" is in the based category, so there's a family of maps $g_t:Z\to W$ each preserving the basepoint, with $g_0=g$ and $g_1=*$ (and continuous when considered as a$[0,1]\times Z\to W$), then the family of maps $f\wedge g_t$ is a nullhomotopy of $f\wedge g$.

There might be a counterexample if the nullhomotopies aren't based. (There are maps that are freely nullhomotopic but not based nullhomotopic. For example the inclusion of the Hawaiian earring $H$ into its cone $(H\times [0,1])/ (H\times\{1\})$, where the earring basepoint $h_0$ is where all the circles meet, and the cone has a basepoint at $(h_0,0)$.)

Comment: Here "nullhomotopic"  is  in the based category. Actually, my question is $f\wedge *$ is homotopic to a constant map?

Comment: In other words, if $Y=X$ and  $f$ is the identity, then is $id\wedge * \simeq *$?

Comment: For example, if $Y=X=S^n$, what is the homotopy type of $id\wedge *:S^n\wedge S^m\to S^n\wedge \{*\}$?

Comment: @LipCaty: It's actually an equality $f\wedge *=*$, because $Y\times\{*\}$ gets quotiented into the basepoint in the definition of the smash product